# Cell Respiration and Oxidative Phosphorylation

Tags: cell-biology, cellular-respiration, mitochondria, energy-metabolism

Why and how does the proton travelling through the stalked particle in the inner mitochondrial membrane, cause a conformational change in the ATPase?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The passage of protons through the F<sub>O</sub> (membrane) portion of the molecule (driven by the electrochemical gradient of protons across the respiratory membrane) generates torque at the interface between the **a** and **c** subunits. This mean that the ring of 10 **c** subunits rotates relative to the **a** subunit. The **γ** subunit in the stalk rotates along with the ring of **c** subunits, while the ring of **α** and **β** subunits in F<sub>1</sub> is constrained to remain static with respect to the **a** subunit because of the interaction with the **δ** and **b** subunits (forming the peripheral stalk). So we have two portions of the molecule the "static" **a-b<sub>2</sub>-δ-α<sub>3</sub>β<sub>3</sub>** part and the rotating **c<sub>10</sub>-γ-ε** part. The **γ** subunit rotates within the **α<sub>3</sub>β<sub>3</sub>** part of F<sub>1</sub> and drives a three-step cycle of conformational changes (via intersubunit interactions) which are linked to the phosphorylation of ADP.

There is a useful animation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_synthase) illustrating the three step catalytic cycle being driven by the rotation of the γ subunit.

(image from Aksimentiev *et al*. (2004) 
Insights into the molecular mechanism of rotation in the F<sub>O</sub> sector of ATP synthase. Biophys J. 86:1332-44)

Comment: For me, ATP synthase is one of the most remarkable features of the cell. Beautiful.